# How to force phantomjs to finish navigating

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I have a problem that my phantomjs loads one site too slow, always at least 60 seconds though on other sites like google.com it takes less than 1 second.

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
service.LoadImages = false;
service.ProxyType = "none";
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

using (IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service ))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://abc.xyz");  //blocks too long
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to force it finish loading after reaching some point so the script will continue?

Comment: When you browse to that one site manually, is it just as slow? Maybe it's just the site and not the script.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The site has DomContentLoaded: 5.7s, and finish is around 60s as above. That's why I think if there's a way to only load some parts like reaching my target table id="abc" , the rest is not important. It seems no way to do that as the driver will block and wait till finishing the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out the reasons why the phantomjs load so slow because the target web has too many extensions, ads... so I switch to chrome and use adblock like [Running Selenium WebDriver using Python with extensions (.crx files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800689/running-webdriver-with-extensions-crx-files)

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are asking now. You have a long loading page that you want to stop after the relevant stuff loads. I run into this same issue with some of the sites that we have at work but I have not tried a programmatic solution. Sorry, I don't know phantomjs but I found some links that I think would be helpful.

The way I would approach it is to wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to fire and then send an ESC to the page. At least that's what I do manually to stop the long loading files that I don't care about so that the execution can continue.

I found this question [How can I wait for the page to be ready in PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143044/how-can-i-wait-for-the-page-to-be-ready-in-phantomjs) Here's the relevant part:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.onCallback = function(data) {
        console.log('Main page is loaded and ready');
        //Do whatever here
    };

    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            window.callPhantom();
        }, false);
        console.log("Added listener to wait for page ready");
    });
};

page.open('https://www.google.com', function(status) {});
```

Once you detect `DOMContentLoaded`, use `sendkeys()` to send the ESC key. I honestly don't know if this will work but it's where I would start. Hopefully it will get you started.